# libgit2sharp exception "cross host redirect not allowed"

Tags: redirect, host, libgit2, libgit2sharp, git-fetch

```
Windows 7 
ASP.NET MVC 4 
LibGit2Sharp 0.21.0.176 
Visual Studio Premium 2012 Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4 
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50709
```

I have various unit/integration tests that call the following code :

```
var remote = Repository.Network.Remote.Add("origin","https://www.github.com/{org}/{repo}.git");
Repository.Network.Fetch(remote, ...)
```

In every case an exception is thrown :

> LibGit2SharpException "cross host redirect not allowed"

Additionally, debug step-through this code the same exception is thrown.

From Windows `cmd.exe` I can run these commands without issue :

```
git clone https://www.github.com/{org}/{repo}.git
cd repo
git fetch
```

The GitHub repo has never been renamed.

One unlikely explanation would be something ( such as spyware/malware ) is redirecting all http requests to an intermediary site. However, I've run full scans and found nothing.

I can run the above tests/code on other dev/test/build workstations without this result.

Comment: Have you seen this issue: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1160

Comment: Duh... ;-) ... Have you tried checking the proxy setting on that machine? And capturing the https headers with Fiddler on that machine. Just running curl --verbose should show you any redirects... Like if I go to one of my repos via the ".git"  "curl --verbose 'https://www.github.com/playscriptredux/playscript.git'" I get a "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" response as you should not include the "www" in the repo URI. It is a 'faulted' test using curl, but it will at least show you if github moved the repo.

Comment: for me , `curl --verbose "https://github.com/{org-name}/{repo-name}.git"` responds with error `301 Moved Permanently` `Location: github.com/{org-name}/{repo-name}` which makes little sense because `curl --verbose "https://github.com/{org-name}/{repo-name}"` returns `404 Not Found` ... but please note this test produces identical responses on both the problem and the non-problem machines